# sql trigger functions - Error "returned more than one row"

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers

I've created a postgresql database using pgadmin. 
 I need a trigger/functions that deals with new purchases:

`purchases_ait` triggered by adding to `purchases`; checks inventory before adding purchase to `purchases` table, and raises an exception if there's not enough; if no exception, subtracts sold quantity from `inventory` and adds it to `purchases`.

---

`Purchases.ait` throws an error message: `more than one row is returned`. Please tell me why this is occuring. I think it could have to do with the logical ordering, such as the if/then and/or begin/end statements. But I haven't been able to figure it out. Help much appreciated!

**Purchases_ait:** (Original `create function` code, trigger code)

```
CREATE FUNCTION purchases_ait() 
   RETURNS TRIGGER 
   LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.quantity > quantity 
    FROM public.inventory THEN 
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'We do not have that much of that item left.';
    END IF;
  UPDATE public.inventory
     SET quantity = quantity - NEW.quantity
   WHERE item_id = NEW.item_id;
   RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
--trigger code --
CREATE TRIGGER purchases_ait 
   AFTER INSERT
   ON public.purchases
   FOR EACH ROW
       EXECUTE PROCEDURE purchases_ait()
```

Comment: I don't think the trigger should return that error. I'm used to getting that error when a sub query returns multiple rows and is used in an ordinal comparison ... are you sure the error message is really coming from the trigger and not another statement you're running?

Comment: Please paste your code which is calling this trigger.

Comment: `IF NEW.quantity > quantity 
    FROM public.inventory` is invalid PL/pgSQL - I am surprised that your trigger function even compiles. Please post the **complete** `create function` code, the corresponding `create trigger` statements and the SQL statement that fires the trigger

Comment: You missed a ```WHERE``` which would return the quantity of the ```NEW.item_id``` and hence, the multiple rows.

Comment: Kunal, I added my where clause `item_id = NEW.item_id;` to the IF statement in my first function, but i still get the same error message

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I recreated the `create function` and `create trigger` codes

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. The two problems were:

- changed it to a `BEFORE` rather than an `AFTER` function
- changed it to a `FOR EACH STATEMENT` rather than a `FOR EACH ROW` application